# Pulling variable names when using pandas and statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I'm trying to access the names of variables from the results generated by `statsmodels`. I'll elaborate more after the example code.

```
import scikits.statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
data = sm.datasets.longley.load()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.exog, columns=data.exog_name)
y = data.endog
df['intercept'] = 1.
olsresult = sm.OLS(y, df).fit()
```

This summary output includes the variable names. When you call something like olsresult.params it returns the following:

```
In [21]: olsresult.params
Out[21]: 
GNPDEFL           15.061872
GNP               -0.035819
UNEMP             -2.020230
ARMED             -1.033227
POP               -0.051104
YEAR            1829.151465
intercept   -3482258.634596
```

Now what I'm curious about doing is creating something like a dictionary with the variable name as a key and the parameter value as the value. So, something like `{'GNPDELF':15.0618, 'GNP':-0.035819}` and so on. If it's impossible to do this, is there any other way to access the variable name and value individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always worth trying the obvious.. :^)

```
In [14]: olsresult.params
Out[14]: 
GNPDEFL           15.061872
GNP               -0.035819
UNEMP             -2.020230
ARMED             -1.033227
POP               -0.051104
YEAR            1829.151465
intercept   -3482258.634597

In [15]: dict(olsresult.params)
Out[15]: 
{'ARMED': -1.0332268671737328,
 'GNP': -0.035819179292614578,
 'GNPDEFL': 15.061872271452557,
 'POP': -0.051104105653539733,
 'UNEMP': -2.0202298038172479,
 'YEAR': 1829.151464613984,
 'intercept': -3482258.6345966831}
```

See also the `.to_dict()` method of `Series` objects.

Comment: Yep, probably should have thought of that first. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

`olsresult.params` is a pandas.Series object which is dict like, maybe you don`t need to convert to a dict.

```
In [12]: olsresult.params.get('GNP')
Out[12]: -0.035819179292566283

In [13]: olsresult.params['GNP']
Out[13]: -0.035819179292566283

In [14]: for key, value in olsresult.params.iteritems():
   ....:     print key, value
   ....:
GNPDEFL 15.0618722714
GNP -0.0358191792926
UNEMP -2.02022980382
ARMED -1.03322686717
POP -0.0511041056537
YEAR 1829.15146461
intercept -3482258.6346
```

Comment: +1; this is an excellent point.  I may have done a twist on the XY problem, namely answered how to do what the OP asked and didn't think about the fact it probably isn't needed!